# send and recv on different threads

Tags: c++, objective-c, sockets

I'm developing a basic matchmaking server. The basic process goes like this:

1. Client connects to server, reporting the client's name and the type of match they are looking for
2. Server reports back all possible matches
3. Client selects which match he/she would like to be paired with
4. Server matches the two clients

The problem is that each time a client connects, I need to report to all possible matches this new client, and report all possible matches to that new connecting client (thus while unmatched a client must always be ready to `recv` from the server).  At the same time, the client may at any point select a match, or disconnect (thus the client must always be ready to `send` and the server must be ready to `recv`)

I suspect that the real solution to this problem is to use threading, a background `recv` thread for the clients and the server, and a main user-interacting `send` thread.

So I have two questions relating to this:

1. Is it save to `send` and `recv` with the same socket connection simultaneously on different threads?
2. Is this even the right way to handle this?

(Tagged as C++ and obj-c because the sever is built in C++ and client is obj-c)

Comment: I know you said the project wasn't specific to Objective-C, but the platforms provide Grand Central Dispatch which makes establishing scalable asych. I/O relatively painless. There is a small learning curve, but it functions well for listening/recv/sending and you can create new queues for each socket if that seems necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is safe to `recv()` on one thread and `send()` on another thread using the same socket.

Server-side, using dedicated threads will only work effectively if you have relatively few clients simultaneously connected to the server at the same time.  If scalability is an issue, you need to use asynchronous I/O, or even I/O completion ports if possible, to manage multiple clients on a single thread, keeping the number of needed threads down to a minimum.

Comment: Define "relatively few"?  Do you mean on the order of 10 or so, 10s of clients, 100s of clients?  The scalability of this server is a concern, but I don't anticipate a large number of clients simultaneously connecting to this server at once

Comment: Anything more than a few 100 clients, you should look into using alternative threading models.

Comment: I disagree. It is entirely a question of your machine's capacity. There are TCP servers out there that routinely handle thousands if not tens of thousands of connections via threads.

Comment: @EJP: thousands of *simultaneous* threads? The OS runs into problems trying to run thousands of threads at one time within a single process. At least on 32-bit versions, since 64-bit versions have more resources available.

Comment: "it is safe to recv() on one thread and send() on another thread using the same socket." - can you cite this?

Answer (score 1):

It is safe in any reasonable socket library implementation. It is also the right way to do it.